# DApps that require stake

Tags: dapp-development

Does anyone knows apps that use the concept of proof-of-stake of ERC20 tokens?

For example, applications like STEEM, that uses and its STEEM POWER.
"STEEM Power is what gives you influence on Steemit. The more SP you have, the more money you give to authors with an upvote as well as the greater the curation rewards you can earn. There is a very small 'interest' rate earned by holding STEEM Power." By https://www.steem.center/index.php?title=STEEM_Power_(SP)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken between the ethereum POS (proof of stake) protocol and the concept of ERC20 tokens stakeholders.

POS is a consensus algorithm and protocol that came to replace the POW (Proof of work) for validating blocks between stakers (miners in POW).

On the other hand, token stakeholders are the participants that buy tokens during or after the ICO (Initial coin offering) phase of a token.
Based on their stake amount, combined with the logic in the smart contracts related to the respective dApp, stakeholders will benefit from a certain value that, in general, is proportional to the amount of tokens they have (or stake).
In case of Steemit, as you said the more SP tokens you have, the more money you give to authors with your upvote etc...
You can have a look at the popular ICOs, categorized, on [ICO bench](https://icobench.com/)